Dependency undefined unless @Inject() used
I'm running into a very troubling issue with NestJS and dependency injection.
Here is my NestJS Controller:
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common'
import { TestService } from './TestService.service'

@Controller()
export class TestController {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  @Get('join')
  join() {
    this.service.foo()
    return 'success'
  }
}

Here is my NestJS Service:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  foo() {
    console.log('foo')
  }
}

Here is my AppModule:
@Module({
  providers: [
    TestService,
  ],
  controllers: [
    TestController,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

Calling the above route throws an error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foo')

If I annotate the controller with property injection like so:
import { Controller, Get, Inject } from '@nestjs/common'
import { TestService } from './TestService.service'

@Controller()
export class TestController {
  constructor(
  @Inject(TestService) // <----- HERE
  private testService: TestService
) {}

  @Get('join')
  join() {
    this.service.foo()
    return 'success'
  }
}

Then the call is a success. It would seem that without property-based injection, Nest DI isn't registering my service.
Any ideas what could be wrong here?
NestJS deps:
"@nestjs/common": "^10.3.8",
"@nestjs/core": "^10.3.7",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.3.7",


you're using property decorator wrongly. Read the docs again. Besides that, everything seems fine.

If I remember correctly, NestJS uses the private readonly modifiers (or protected readonly) to distinguish an injection from anything else. It might be because you're missing the readonly part after your private when you're injecting the service without the decorator

I think I've narrowed it down to being an issue using ESBuild, which NestJS does not support. I noticed to very different outputs when building with webpack vs esbuild, and ES being unable to support Nest decorators. There's a github issue out there describing it, though I couldn't find it just now.
